# Trying to source bashrc: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, software-installation, bashrc

I'm trying to install openfoam4. I have installed it and edited the .bashrc file to have the line:

```
source /opt/openfoam4/etc/bashrc
```

I tried to run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

and get:

```
bash:/opt/openfoam4/etc/bashrc: file not found
```

When I run `ls -la ~/ | more` I see the .bashrc file as well as some .bashrc.swm and .bashrc.swn files. I know they were created by exiting the editor incorrectly.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Whats the output of `ls /opt/openfoam4/etc/bashrc`?

Comment: `.bashrc` (with a period in front of it) is not the same as `bashrc`. Try changing your `source` line to `source /opt/openfoam4/etc/.bashrc`

Comment: File /opt/openfoam4/etc/bashrc does not exist, the error occurs when the file is sourced within ~/.bashrc. Type: ls -A /opt/openfoam4/etc and check the files there, I think you have a typo, as suggested above, it could be '.bashrc' instead of 'bashrc'.

Comment: The output is: ls: cannot access 'opt/openfoam4/etc/bashrc': no such file or directory

Comment: I typed the line: ls -A /opt/openfoam4/etc and it said there was no file or directory

Comment: and I see that my .bashrc file is in /home/eric  Is this correct?

Comment: Here is the installation file I'm trying to follow: complete the following

Open the .bashrc file in the user’s home directory in an editor, e.g. by typing in a terminal window (note the dot)
gedit ~/.bashrc
At the bottom of that file, add the following line (see Note 1 below) and save the file
source /opt/openfoam4/etc/bashrc
Open a new terminal window (see Note 2 below) and test that the simpleFoam application, from the OpenFOAM package, is working by typing
simpleFoam -help
A “Usage” message should appear. Your installation and user configuration is complete.

Comment: Try: `sudo mkdir -pv /opt/openfoam4/etc && sudo touch /opt/openfoam4/etc/bashrc` For others see here: http://openfoam.org/download/4-0-ubuntu/

Comment: Thank you andrew.46. I made the directories but couldn't run: simpleFoam -help. It read siplefoam: command not found

Comment: @E.Graz I installed openfoam on my own system and my suspicion is that you have a faulty installation with some missing config files at least. Have a look at my answer and see if it fixes the issue...

Answer (score 3):

Your installation of OpenFoam4 is *broken* as on installation on my Xenial system there is quite a *comprehensive* `/opt/openfoam4/etc/bashrc` configuration file in place that is appropriately sourced from the user file `~/.bashrc`.

I strongly suggest that you *reinstall the application* to correct missing files in `/opt`. For Trusty and Xenial make sure you have followed these steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu
sudo sh -c "wget -O - http://dl.openfoam.org/gpg.key | apt-key add -"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install openfoam4
```

Then add the following line to `~/.bashrc`, making sure that it is only there *once*:

```
source /opt/openfoam4/etc/bashrc
```

To test this run the following commands, as demonstrated on my own system:

```
andrew@athens:~$ source ~/.bashrc
andrew@athens:~$ simpleFoam -help

Usage: simpleFoam [OPTIONS]
options:
  -case <dir>       specify alternate case directory, default is the cwd
  -noFunctionObjects
                    do not execute functionObjects
  -parallel         run in parallel
  -postProcess      Execute functionObjects only
  -roots <(dir1 .. dirN)>
                    slave root directories for distributed running
  -srcDoc           display source code in browser
  -doc              display application documentation in browser
  -help             print the usage

Using: OpenFOAM-4.0 (see www.OpenFOAM.org)
Build: 4.0-665f1db4c1f1

andrew@athens:~$
```

And you should *now* see a very comprehensive configuration file in place at `/opt/openfoam4/etc/bashrc`...

**References:**

- [OpenFoam: Download v4.0 | Ubuntu](http://openfoam.org/download/4-0-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you that the file `/opt/openfoam4/etc/bashrc` (which you try to source from `~/.bashrc`) does not exist. It's not complaining about your `~/.bashrc` file in itself.